# React passing additional classNames to child component in addition to other props

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to pass additional classNames into a child component, and also pass down any other props.

For example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        <Child
            className="parent-class"
            flavor="chocolate"
        />
    }
}

class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        <div className="child-class" {...props}>

        </div>
    }
}
```

In this case, I would like the Child component div to have the "flavor" prop, and also have *both* classes "parent-class" and "child-class". However as it is, the className="child-class" will be overwritten by {...props}.

The only workaround I can think of is putting the {...props} before the className in the Child component:

```
<div {...props} className={`child-class ${props.className}`}>
```

Is this the only workaround? Or is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I typically use the [classnames package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) and the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) for things like this.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        <Child
            className="parent-class"
            flavor="chocolate"
        />
    }
}

class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        const { className, ...rest } = this.props;
        const childClassNames = classNames('child-class', className);

        return (
            <div className={childClassNames} {...rest}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can call `rest` whatever you like, e.g. `...props` will create an object variable called `props` which would contain everything from `this.props` except for `className`.

Also, the classnames package is very widely used, and lets you do other cool things like conditionally include class names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using functional components, the approach is almost identical to Bryan Downings answer. For simplicities sake I am only posting the implemented child component.

```
import { Tabs as AntdTabs } from 'antd'

/**
 * simplified exmaple, based on our custom Antd Tabs*
 * AntD Tabs with custom styling pre-applied.
 * @param props The default TabsProps.
 * @returns Antd Tabs.
 */
const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {

    const {
        className,
        ...rest
    } = props

    const cls = classnames(className, 'custom-tabs')
    
    return (
        <>
            <AntdTabs 
                className={cls}
                {...rest} >
            </AntdTabs>
        </>
    )
}

export { Tabs }
```